# How to check if data is already in database using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-4

**Situation:**

- My PHP script will run once a way.
- and that will store data in my database.
- Since 1 week is good enough for me, so I only want to keep just that.
- Let's say if today is Friday OR **5** (in my case).
- Is there a way to check if `date == 5` is `already exist` in the database, and possibly override it with the one ?
- If today is Friday/5, then all the old data with `date == 5` should be **overridden** and store the new one instead.
- Literally, I only want to store one full week worth of data.
- Tomorrow, and the next will repeat the same logic.

Here is how I insert my data into my database :

```
$data              = new Data;
$data->name        = $name;
$data->description = $description;
$data->dayOfWeek   = $today; // could be 0,1,2,3,4,5,6
$data->save();
```

I am not sure, how do I accomplish that in Laravel. 
Any tip/suggestion will be much appreciated !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you do this outside of your foreach loop - before you insert

> Data::where("dayOfWeek","=", $today )->delete();

That should take care of what you want, then you can continue insert just like normal:

```
$data              = new Data;
$data->name        = $name;
$data->description = $description;
$data->dayOfWeek   = $today; // could be 0,1,2,3,4,5,6
$data->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) eg. like that

```
INSERT INTO `data` (`name`, `description`, `day`) VALUES (:name, :description, :day)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = VALUES(name), description = VALUES(description)
```

Of course you have to declare unique key on `day` field to make it work.

Comment: Thanks, this will at least get me thinking in the right direction. Do you know how to do this in Laravel ?  I normally - just do `$data->save();` Laravel will save it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly get the data from the database;

```
$data = Data::where('dayOfWeek', $today)->first();
```

Then check to see if the data is there, if it is update if not create.

```
if (!is_null($data)){
    $data->update($new_attribute_data)
}
else {
    Data::create($new_attribute_data);
}
```

As a note: Using the update method can require you to fill the $fillable array within your model if you putting GET or POST data into it. You can do it like so;

```
class Data extends Eloquent {
    ...
    protected $fillable = ['name','description','dayOfWeek'];
}
```

And Laravel will fill the Model Attribute with the corresponding data within the Input.

**EDIT:**

As a faster way for the above method, use the `updateOrCreate` method;

```
Data::updateOrCreate(['dayOfWeek' => $today], $new_attribute_data);
```

This will search for Data models with attributes that match the first parameters, and will update its other attributes with the second parameter. [Ref](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, an UPDATE of the old row is performed. For example, if column a is declared as UNIQUE and contains the value 1, the following two statements have identical effect:

Sample Code:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (4,5,6)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=9;
```